# Flask keeps loading optional variable in function

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to load an image, based on what the user selects in a select box.

html:

```
<div class='image-container' id='image'>
        <h3>Index: {{ photo_index }}</h3>
        <h3>Filename: {{ image }}</h3>
        <img src="{{ url_for('images.static', filename=image) }} " id="the-photo">
</div>
<div class='button-container' id='buttons'>
   <form action="" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="prev-next-buttons">
       <input type="submit" value="Show prev photo" name='prev_photo'>
       <input type="submit" value="Show next photo" name='next_photo'>
       <br/>
       <input type="submit" value="Show random photo" name='random_photo'>
       <button type='button' id='rotate-button' onclick="rotateMe('#the-photo')">Rotate Photo</button>
   </form>
   <h3>Choose image from list:</h3>
   <form method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="photo-select">
       <select id="select-image" onfocus='this.size=5;' onblur='this.size=1' onchange="this.size=1;  this.blur(); this.form.submit()">
           {% for eimage in image_list %}
               <option {% if eimage == image %} selected {% endif %}
                href = "{{ url_for('main', chosen_image=eimage) }}"
                >
                   {{eimage}}
               </option>
           {% endfor %}
       </select>
   </form>
</div>
```

routes.py

```
CUR_PHOTO_INDEX = 0
images = os.listdir(IMAGE_FOLDER)
image_urls = create_urls(images)
image_urls.append('favicon.ico')
num_images = len(image_urls) - 1

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main(chosen_image="Penguins.jpg"):
    # if request.method == "POST":
    global CUR_PHOTO_INDEX
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'prev-next-buttons' in request.form:
            CUR_PHOTO_INDEX = return_index(request.form, CUR_PHOTO_INDEX)
            # print("Showing index", CUR_PHOTO_INDEX)
        elif 'photo-select' in request.form:
            CUR_PHOTO_INDEX = image_urls.index(chosen_image)
            # print("\n", indx, "\n")
            print("\n", chosen_image, CUR_PHOTO_INDEX, "\n")
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title="Local Image Viewer",
                           photo_index=CUR_PHOTO_INDEX,
                           image=image_urls[CUR_PHOTO_INDEX],
                           image_list=image_urls)
```

What I'm expecting to happen, is when the user selects an option from the list, it sends that image name (a string, `eimage`) to `main()`, and then looks for that index in `image_urls.index(chosen_image)`.  But, whenever I do select an option, it just rpints the "Penguins.jpg" and its index over and over.

What am I overlooking to send the selected image name to the `main()` function?

Comment: When would your second if ever be true? There's no 'prev-next-buttons' in your form as far as I can see. And what is supposed to be populating the 'photo-select' hidden input? (And, you absolutely definitely should not be using a global for CUR_PHOTO_INDEX.)

Comment: Why do you have `global CUR_PHOTO_INDEX` btw?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Sorry, I tried to post as little code as I could to keep it succinct, but have updated it.  I have a global `CUR_PHOTO_INDEX` because, despite declaring it above, I get `local variable 'CUR_PHOTO_INDEX` referenced before assignment when I don't include that. (Edit: the `global` declaration was a kludge from earlier. I've since removed it, and simply declared it in the `main()` function. ...but now the prev/next buttons don't do anything.)

Comment: @roganjosh - so I can use that variable in the function. I declared it above the function but have to declare it in the function since I assign something to it. I am currently trying to work around that.

Comment: I have even tried doing `global CUR_PHOTO_INDEX // CUR_PHOTO_INDEX = 0` above `@app.route()`, and changed to `def main(CUR_PHOTO_INDEX, chosen_image=image_urls[0]):` but get an error `main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'CUR_PHOTO_INDEX'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @F. Pareto, part of the issue was I wasn't passing the parameter to the `app.route("/")`.

The second issue was my use of a global variable to try and keep track of the current index.  Thanks greatly to [this Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46567275/4650297), I have created a class to keep track of the index and can iterate through that.

html:

```
<div class='image-container' id='image'>
   <h3>Index: {{ photo_index }}</h3>
   <h3>Filename: {{ image }}</h3>
   <img src="{{ url_for('images.static', filename=image) }} " id="the-photo">
 </div>
 <div class='button-container' id='buttons'>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="prev-next-buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Show prev photo" name='prev-photo'>
        <input type="submit" value="Show next photo" name='next-photo'>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Show random photo" name='random-photo'>
        <button type='button' id='rotate-button' onclick="rotateMe('#the-photo')">Rotate Photo</button>
    </form>
    <h3>Choose image from list:</h3>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="photo-select">
        <select name="select-image" onfocus='this.size=5;' onblur='this.size=1' onchange="this.size=1;  this.blur(); this.form.submit()">
            {% for eimage in image_list %}
                <option 
                {% if eimage == image %} selected {% endif %}
                value = {{ eimage }}
                >
                    {{eimage}}
                </option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

routes.py

```
images = os.listdir(IMAGE_FOLDER)
def create_urls(files):
    image_urls = []
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".jpg"):
            image_urls.append(file)
    return image_urls


image_urls = create_urls(images)
image_urls.append('favicon.ico')
# Subtract 2 below, so you don't include the
# favicon.ico
num_images = len(image_urls) - 2


class Photo_Index():
    def __init__(self, index=0):
        self.index = index

    def increase_number(self):
        if self.index == num_images:
            self.index = 0
        else:
            self.index = self.index + 1
        return self.index

    def decrease_number(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            self.index = num_images
        else:
            self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.index

    def random_number(self):
        self.index = random.randint(0, num_images)
        return self.index

    def set_number(self, number):
        self.index = number
        return self.index

photo_index_obj = Photo_Index()


def update_index(rqst):
    if 'prev-photo' in rqst.form:
        photo_index_obj.decrease_number()
    elif 'next-photo' in rqst.form:
        photo_index_obj.increase_number()
    elif 'random-photo' in rqst.form:
        photo_index_obj.random_number()


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/<chosen_image>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main(chosen_image=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'prev-next-buttons' in request.form:
            update_index(request)
        elif 'photo-select' in request.form:
            img = request.form.get("select-image")
            photo_index_obj.set_number(image_urls.index(str(img)))
        else:
            print("not a real POST")
    if request.method == "GET":
        if chosen_image is not None:
            photo_index_obj.set_number(image_urls.index(chosen_image))
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title="Local Image Viewer",
                           photo_index=photo_index_obj.index,
                           image=image_urls[photo_index_obj.index],
                           image_list=image_urls)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have not defined a query parameter in your route. `url_for` will return an URL to your endpoint, and since it has no way of communicating the value for `chosen_image` via this URL, your method will always use the default value.

Try something like

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/<chosen_image>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main(chosen_image="Penguins.jpg"):
    # the rest of your method
```

Comment: So I updated the function to be `def main(chosen_image=image_urls[0]):` and added the line as you suggested, but am still not getting the chosen image as the image showing...I suspect the reason is my `gloabl CUR_PHOTO_INDEX` in there, that I need to fix/work around...

Comment: Could you update your question to reflect the current state of your code?

Comment: I think I found my solution, I need to use a class to advance the photo index, avoiding the global variable.  This is part of that solution though, so thanks very much! (I'm fine-tuning it and making sure it works, but will post as an Answer later).